# Is it possible to reuse the same column for multiple foreign key references in JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an existing database structure that has Project, TableA, and TableB.  TableA has a Composite Primary Key consisting of a non-unique varchar `id` and a varchar `project_id`.  TableB has a Primary Key only on its `id` column, but also has a FK reference to project through `project_id`.  I now want to add a TableC that I want to ALWAYS reference a Project, but has a nullable/optional reference TableA.  TableC should only ever have one of either TableA or TableB reference, but never both.

[Desired schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQo4j.png)

Is there a way to set up my JPA entities in a way that the TableC has both the `Project` and `ObjectA` references but re-uses the `project_id` column?

If I specify the `@JoinColumn` to use the same column name, it fails to build due to "repeated column in mapping".  If I specify the `project` reference as not `insertable` or `updateable`, then I can't include the a Project reference alone.

```java
@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id
    private String id;
}

public class TableAId implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private Project project;
}


@Entity
@IdClass(TableAId.class)
public class TableA {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable = false)
    private Project project;

}


@Entity
public class TableB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", nullable = false)
    private Project project;
}


@Entity
public class TableC {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "tablea_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id")
    })
    private TableA tableA;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tableb_id")
    private TableB tableB;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is common. In your TableC entity, you just need to mark one of the  "project_id" join column definitions as insertable=false, updatable=false to indicate one as read-only. This allows the other to control setting the FK and will be what is used if the two are ever out of synch.

```
@Entity
public class TableC {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "tablea_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private TableA tableA;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tableb_id")
    private TableB tableB;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
    private Project project;
}
```

Comment: ChatGPT gave me a similar answer too :).  Two problems with it, the first is that you can't mix insertable and non-insertable columns for a single entity reference (according to hibernate's error message).  The second is that, making `tableA`'s @JoinColumns not insertable or updatable means I can't persist a `TableC` instance that includes a `tableA` reference.  It's literally telling Hibernate to not store anything in those columns.

To be fair, I am working with an older version of hibernate (5.1), so maybe newer versions support this better.

Comment: First issue is hibernate specific likely version specific - this works with other providers and allowed by the spec - check for bugs. Workaround is to make both TableA's join columns read-only and then add a basic mapping for the "tablea_id" that you would have to set yourself from the mapping.

Comment: I've tested a few versions of hibernate, including the latest, and they all gave similar message.  Out of curiosity, I also tried a version of EclipseLink and it generated the schema, but wouldn't insert a new TableC record with a TableA reference.  I was hoping to avoid a workaround like you described, but that does look like it's going to work as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: EclipseLink later versions certainly should have worked - I've used a similar setup for project with it in the past. If you want to go that route, post the error with it.